# Understanding P&L from tradingview position tool

Tags: day-trading

I'm really trying to understand how much profit and loss I would make when placing the LONG or SHORT position tool in TradingView.

I understand that with a $1000 account size, 0.01 lots == $10 and also 1% Risk == $10, that at 1.5 the profit would be 0.00146.

Using [this page](https://www.tradingview.com/chart/BTCUSD/0CRpHEGd-LONG-SHORT-POSITION-TOOL-An-In-Depth-Look-at-Using-This-Tool/) I am still left with these questions:

1. Why is the quantity 1030927 if the calculation is Qty=Risk/(Entry price-Stop price)?
2. What is the tick? Is this basically a pip?
3. Why is the profit target $1015.05? How is this calculated?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the same page:

> Why is the quantity 1030927 if the calculation is Qty=Risk/(Entry price-Stop price)?

quantity = 1% * $1,000 * (0.67834 - 0.67737) / 0.01

> What is the tick? Is this basically a pip?

"Tick = A tick is a measure of the minimum upward or downward movement in price," in this case 0.00001

> Why is the profit target $1015.05? How is this calculated?

Based on the *top info panel* screenshot, it's "the hypothetical account balance after the take profit target is achieved", i.e. $1000 + (1,030,927 * 0.00146 * 0.01)

Comment: So, pip is not tick?

Comment: In forex, a pip is usually the 4th decimal. A tick is the smallest possible price increment (on this platform). Sometimes they're the same but it doesn't have to be that way. Hopefully this helps: https://www.babypips.com/learn/forex/pips-and-pipettes